# Save dynamic input with angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to know how can I add the array that I create in the value of my form to send it to laravel and store it in my database
to create the inputs I am doing them dynamically, and in the checkboxes I am creating them from the component and printing them in the html

In my component I create the input and 3 checkboxes

```
    public steps: any[] = [{
        id: 1,
        paso: '',
        accion: '',
        punto_critico: '',
        razon: '',
        fichero: ''
      }];
      
      turnsArray: Array<any> = [];
      turns = [
        { name: '1 Turno', id:'1' },
        { name: '2 Turno', id:'2' },
        { name: '3 Turno', id:'3' }
      ];
Addsteps() {
    this.steps.push({
      id: this.steps.length + 1,
      paso: '',
      accion: '',
      punto_critico: '',
      razon: '',
      fichero: ''
    });
  }

  removeStep(i:number){
    this.steps.splice(i,1);
  }
    
  onChange(turn:string, isChecked:boolean) {
    if(isChecked) {
      this.turnsArray.push(turn);
    } else {
      let index = this.turnsArray.indexOf(turn);
      this.turnsArray.splice(index,1);
    }
  }
```

And in my HTML is like this

```
<div class="card-body">
    <section class="container mb-4 p-3" name="steps" *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index;" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h4>Paso {{i + 1}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Paso</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="step.paso" name="paso_{{step.id}}" placeholder="Paso"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Accion</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="step.accion" name="accion_{{step.id}}" placeholder="Accion"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Punto critico</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="step.punto_critico" name="punto_critico_{{step.id}}" placeholder="Punto critico"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Razon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="step.razon" name="razon_{{step.id}}" placeholder="Razon"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fichero</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="step.fichero" name="fichero_{{step.id}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeStep(i)">Remover paso</button>
    </section>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="Addsteps()">Agregar paso</button> 
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="turn" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Turno</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of turns">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="turn" (change)="onChange(item.name, $event.target.checked)" type="checkbox">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                {{item.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do to storage in the value form hat i mark in yellow

[image]

When I make the submit clicking the button I call the onSubmit method

```
onSubmit(form){
    console.log(this.project);
    this._projectService.create(this.token, this.project, this.steps, this.turnsArray).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest solution to achieve this is by using `ReactiveForms`. With Reactive forms it will be easier to create `FormArray` and the value of the form can be easily accessed using `value` property of the `formGroup`

Lets begin by first taking care of the `id` property of the step. You are assigning your `id` property using `id: this.steps.length + 1,` Now consider below sequence of events

> - Insert 3 items to produce `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]`. I have removed other properties for simplicity
> - Remove Item 2. We now have `[{id: 1}, {id: 3}]`
> - Insert new item. We now have `[{id: 1}, {id: 3}, {id: 3}]`
>   We now have 2 items with `id = 3`, which is probably not what we want

We will solve above by creating a `currentStepId` and a `getNewId()` method

```typescript
currentStepId = 0;
getNewId() {
  this.currentStepId += 1;
  return this.currentStepId;
}
```

Next step will be to import `ReactiveFormsModule`

```typescript
import { ..., ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ..., ReactiveFormsModule ],
})
```

I will inject `FormBuilder` to assist with the creation of the `formGroup`

We will begin by a plan of how we want our form value to be. I will assume below structure

```json
{
  steps: [{ id: 1, paso: "", accion: "", punto_critico: "", razon: "", fichero: "" }],
  turns = [];
}
```

We can define `newStep` property

```typescript
  get newStep(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [this.getNewId()],
      paso: "",
      accion: "",
      punto_critico: "",
      razon: "",
      fichero: ""
    });
  }
```

And define our `formGroup`

```typescript
  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  stepsForm = this.fb.group({
    steps: [this.newStep],
    turns: [[]]
  })
```

Lets now define the functions to add and remove steps

```typescript
get steps(): FormArray {
  return this.stepsForm.get('steps') as FormArray
}
Addsteps() {
  this.steps.push(this.newStep);
}
removeStep(i: number) {
  this.steps.controls.splice(i, 1);
  this.stepsForm.updateValueAndValidity()
}
```

Finally We need  to handle `turns`

```
get turns() {
  return this.stepsForm.get('turns')
}
onChange(turn: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    
    if (isChecked) {
      console.log(this.turns.value);
      this.turns.setValue([...this.turns.value, turn]);
    } else {
      this.turns.setValue(this.turns.value.filter(a => a != turn ));
    }
  }
```

With the above you will need to change your html

```html
<div class="card-body" [formGroup]='stepsForm'>
    <fieldset formArrayName='steps'>
        <legend>Steps</legend>
        <fieldset class="container mb-4 p-3" name="steps" *ngFor="let step of steps.controls; let i = index;"
            style="vertical-align: middle;" [formGroupName]='i'>
            <legend>Step {{ i + 1 }}</legend>
            <div class="col-6">
                <h4>Paso {{i + 1}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Paso</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="paso" placeholder="Paso"/>
            </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Accion</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accion"  placeholder="Accion"/>
            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Punto critico</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="punto_critico" placeholder="Punto critico"/>
            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Razon</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="razon" placeholder="Razon"/>
            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Fichero</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" formControlName="fichero" />
            </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeStep(i)">Remover paso</button>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="Addsteps()">Agregar paso</button>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="turn" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Turno</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of turnsList">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="turn" (change)="onChange(item.name, $event.target['checked'])" type="checkbox">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                {{item.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Please See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wjkpgb)

Comment: Hi, I make all the changes into my project but i'm getting other error about the observable and i dont know what to do. every time i click the submit button in the console appear ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Where are you using `length` property ? In my solution there is no place with the length property,

Comment: Hi, I know that is long time ago this question but I have a new one... I cant add a file in base64 to send to my API, did you know how can I make that? i try followin this https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/file-upload-with-angular-reactive-forms-exampleexample.html

Comment: Sorry cant help you

Comment: @Hi, how can I make to fill the steps array when I want to edit after I make a register? I try with  ` response.project.steps.forEach( valor => this.steps.push(valor))` but I get a error